# I want to access each data value of the below json in Angularjs . But I am unable to find a way

Tags: angularjs, json, openehr

I want to access each data value of the below JSON in Angularjs. But I am unable to find a way. let say I want to access type, name, magnitude, units of the below query. So how to access that, can anybody help me regarding about this, please?

```
{
"**openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.body_temperature.v1/data[at0002]/events[at0003]/data[at0001]/items[at0004]/value**":{

"type": "DV_QUANTITY",

"name": "Temperature",

"serie":[
{
"magnitude": 34,

"units": "°C",

"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"

}

]
},
```

Comment: Paste here clear json.

Comment: And please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

you may do something like this with ng-repeat

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.body_temperature.v1/data[at0002]/events[at0003]/data[at0001]/items[at0004]/value":{
"type": "DV_QUANTITY",
"name": "Temperature",
"serie":[
{
"magnitude": 34,
"units": "°C",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"magnitude": 34,
"units": "°C",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
},
{
"magnitude": 38,
"units": "°C",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
},
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.blood_pressure.v1/data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value":{
"type": "DV_QUANTITY",
"name": "Systolic",
"serie":[
{
"magnitude": 4,
"units": "mm[Hg]",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"magnitude": 9,
"units": "mm[Hg]",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
},
{
"magnitude": 7,
"units": "mm[Hg]",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
},
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.blood_pressure.v1/data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0005]/value":{
"type": "DV_QUANTITY",
"name": "Diastolic",
"serie":[
{
"magnitude": 6,
"units": "mm[Hg]",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"magnitude": 17,
"units": "mm[Hg]",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
},
{
"magnitude": 12,
"units": "mm[Hg]",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
},
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.pulse.v1/data[at0002]/events[at0003]/data[at0001]/items[at0004]/value":{
"type": "DV_QUANTITY",
"name": "Rate",
"serie":[
{
"magnitude": 6,
"units": "/min",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"magnitude": 17,
"units": "/min",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
},
{
"magnitude": 15,
"units": "/min",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
},
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.pulse.v1/data[at0002]/events[at0003]/data[at0001]/items[at0005]/value":{
"type": "DV_CODED_TEXT",
"name": "Regular?",
"serie":[
{
"code": "at0006at1028",
"value": "Regular",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"code": "at0006at1028",
"value": "Irregular",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
},
{
"code": "at0006at1028",
"value": "Irregular",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
},
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.respiration.v1/data[at0001]/events[at0002]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value":{
"type": "DV_QUANTITY",
"name": "Rate",
"serie":[
{
"magnitude": 5,
"units": "/min",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"magnitude": 9,
"units": "/min",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
},
{
"magnitude": 13,
"units": "/min",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
},
"openEHR-EHR-OBSERVATION.respiration.v1/data[at0001]/events[at0002]/data[at0003]/items[at0005]/value":{
"type": "DV_CODED_TEXT",
"name": "Rhythm",
"serie":[
{
"code": "at0006at0007",
"value": "Regular",
"date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
},
{
"code": "at0006at0007",
"value": "Regular",
"date": "2016-12-29 06:49:51"
}
]
}
    
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in name">
<p>{{v.type}}</p>
<p>{{v.name}}</p>
<span ng-repeat="x in v.serie">
   magnitude: {{x.magnitude}},
   units:{{x.units}},
   date:{{x.date}}<br>
</span>
</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .It is working for only one json. Here you are passing whole json into the scope . So if I have multiple jsons like the above ,  how can I do that ?  Can you please tell me ?

Comment: you showed only one json to me so that i worked with available resouces only.....if u provide the data with multiple json then i can update according to that

Comment: where is the whole json??

Comment: E  , I am giving the link for the whole file 
Please find it below
http://codepad.org/IIVXX3Ev

Comment: I want to access each node value ,like previously I told like type, name, magnitude, units  , date of every node .

Comment: Thank you so much @Sa E Chowdary

Comment: is tis is ur desired output

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.jsonObj = {
     "openEHR": {
       "type": "DV_QUANTITY",
       "name": "Temperature",
       "serie": [{
        "magnitude": 34,
        "units": "°C",
        "date": "2016-12-28 13:23:32"
      }]
     }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Type : {{jsonObj.openEHR.type}}<br>
  Name : {{jsonObj.openEHR.name}}<br>
  <div ng-repeat="item in jsonObj.openEHR.serie">
     Magnitude : {{item.magnitude}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a query result from the EHRServer.

The "serie" object is always an array of objects compliant with the "type", so you need to first check the type, to know which fields to expect in the "serie" objects.

For a type = DV_QUANTITY you will always get "magnitude" and "units". The "date" will always be there when you "group by path".

You can find more in the official documentation https://cloudehrserver.com/learn

By the way, I'm the creator of the EHRServer. If you have questions about it, we have a community support chat https://gitter.im/CaboLabs/EHRServer